# Do I need to also add a trigger after using AWS::SNS::Subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I have an `SNS` topic defined as follows

```
  SlmExceedenceTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName:
        Fn::Sub: ${AWS::StackName}-slm-exceedence-topic
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref Environment
```

and I want a lambda function `ExceedenceProcessor` to be executed once we have a notification in the `SNS`. I have thus added the following Subscription

```
ExceedenceProcessorSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt: ExceedenceProcessor.Arn
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !Ref SlmExceedenceTopic
```

This correctly adds the subscription and I can even see it from the `SNS` subscription. However, my function is never executed. I can only get it to execute if I manually add a trigger to the Lambda function targetting the `SNS`.
Isn't adding just a `Subscription` be enough?

Comment: Yes, if you can see the that Subscription is linked to the Lambda function, then that should be enough. How are you testing whether it works? For example, are you sending a message to the Amazon SNS topic and then checking the CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function?

Comment: yes that's how I'm testing it.

Comment: I see the issue is related to permission `User: sns.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:xxx:function:` however I've provided the `AWSLambdaRole` policy to the user making the requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "user" does not invoke the Lambda function. Rather, it is the **Amazon SNS Service** that invokes the Lambda function. That is why the error is saying `User: sns.amazonaws.com is not authorized`

You should add permissions in the Lambda function to allow Amazon SNS to invoke it:

[image: Amazon Lambda permissions]

If your CloudFormation template is creating the AWS Lambda function, it can add these permissions using [AWS::Lambda::Permission - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html).